# Firefox, IE and Chrome different whitespace handling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm curious why I get different results on Chrome and Firefox with this simple code:

1. [Breaks on Chrome](http://www.bootply.com/WzUfwZFpu9)
2. [Works on both Firefox, IE and Chrome](http://www.bootply.com/r11dtBMljk)

The only difference is in HTML layout:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <input class="email" type="text">
    <button class="send pull-right">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

versus this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <input class="email" type="text"><button class="send pull-right">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any recommended fix without ugly hacks and HTML changes?

Comment: By the way which html you want to use?

Comment: Did you specify DOCTYPE ?

Comment: The first link doesn't break in chrome - v37.0.2062.94

Comment: @Vucko on v36.0.1985.143 it breaks. Indeed v37.0.2062.102 works fine. I'm a bit puzzled with that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input>` isn't block elements by default. You must use `float:left` for them:

```
.form-wrapper {overflow:hidden;}
input.email, button.send{float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.form-wrapper {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0; /*set font-size to zero*/
}
input.email {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 16px; /*reset font-size*/
}

button.send {
  background-color: grey;
  border: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 16px; /*reset font-size*/
}
```

[working demo](http://www.bootply.com/QMRcMiEDmH)

**Method 2:**

Use float for inputs and clear the float using `overflow:hidden` to parent div.

[demo](http://www.bootply.com/Xn59YOPwoK)